# Reflected Brownian Motion inside a disk

Tags: partial-differential-equations, brownian-motion

I am studying reflected brownian motion. I have already understood the 1-D case, and I am able to reproduce the probability density functions for reflected brownain motion on arbitrary closed intervals. I think the next simple case is to study reflected brownian motion inside a disk. Is it possible to obtain, as in the 1-d case, closed formulas for the PDF of reflected brownian motion in a disk (whose boundary of reflection would be $\mathbb S^1$)?

p.d. I have searched with keywords "reflected brownian motion+disk" with no avail. I am sure, however, that relevant things to read should exist, thus any reference is welcome!

Comment: you should make your question more precise. I rarely see mathematical questions without the presence of equations or identities. I suggest you sharing what you already know in detail then talk about possible extension

Comment: Well I truly thought the description was clear enough as I am looking for a reference, but alright: consider, for example, the PDE $\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=\nabla^2p$, where $p=p(x,t)$, and $x\in\mathbb D^1\subset\mathbb R^2$. We assume that there are Neumann conditions on the boundary $\partial \mathbb D^1=\mathbb S^1$. I am wondering if there is a closed form solution of the PDE. I understand this may depend on the initial condition one would specify.

Comment: @PepeToro The equation you wrote is the Heat equation, right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Statement_of_the_equation

Comment: @NN2 indeed, thanks, I see there that the domain should be "decomposable" in order to write a closed form solution. Indeed that is why I started with a disk, because I imagine it should be possible to decompose a radial and an angular component. I will write the equation in polar coordinates and suume that the solution is a product of two single variable funtions, as $p(r,\theta,t)=f(r,t)g(\theta,t)$ and see how that goes. However, it would be nice to know a reference for such a closed form solution.